# If selector has attr of array of attrs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my array of attributes :

```
var newIDs = [];
    $element.parents(".comments").find(".comment.new").each(function(idx, el){
    newIDs.push($(this).attr('commentID'));
});
```

Now I have a selector :

```
 html = $(html).find('.comment')
```

I want to narrow down the selector to test if the .comment has any of the arributes in the array above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter:

```
html = $(html).find('.comment').filter(function() {
  return newIDs.indexOf($(this).attr('commentID')) > -1
})
```

Docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

The `.filter` method filters your jQuery collection to a set of items based on an evaluation function. If your function returns true, the item stays, otherwise it's filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`, iterate `.attributes` of `.comment` elements

```
 html = $(html).find('.comment').filter(function(i, el) {
   for (var i = 0; i < el.attributes; i++) {
     if (newIDS.indexOf(el.attributes[i].value) !== -1) {
       return true
     }
   }
   return false
 })
```